# Length of a right Triangle (Java Eclipse): User input chart

Tags: java, eclipse, format, rectangles

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleDriver {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter value of N: ");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("----    ----");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print((i + 1) + "    ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%7.2f", Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

This could be useful to others that are new to coding. I do need help on it though. When you input a number, say 8,

-it is not spaced properly

-The first actual row of data should not include 1.00, 2.00, 3.00

-Personal Preference: I would like to include ---- on the top after the i numbers and | on the side for the J numbers

*What do you guys think?*

Comment: What is this displaying and what would you like to see instead?

Comment: http://snag.gy/pl3x1.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to how your code should look

```
public class TriangleDriver {
    private static final String REQUEST = "Please enter value of N: ";
    private static final String SPACER3 = "   ";
    private static final String SPACER4 = "    ";
    private static final String DIVIDER = "----";
    private static final String FORMAT_ONE = "  %d    ";
    private static final String FORMAT_FIRST_ROW = "%7.0f";
    private static final String FORMAT_ADDITIONAL_ROWS = "%7.2f";
    private static final int HEADER_LINES = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = getIntInput(REQUEST);
        StringBuilder[] result = solution(num);
        printSBArray(result);
    }

    static private int getIntInput(String request){
        System.out.print(request);
        return new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    }

    static private void printSBArray(StringBuilder[] sbArray){
        for (StringBuilder sb : sbArray)
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    static private StringBuilder[] solution(int num){
        StringBuilder output[] = new StringBuilder[num + HEADER_LINES];
        for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = new StringBuilder("");

        // build line 0
        output[0].append(SPACER4 + SPACER4);
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            output[0].append(String.format(FORMAT_ONE, i));
        }

        // build line 1
        output[1].append(DIVIDER + SPACER4);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            output[1].append(String.format(DIVIDER + SPACER3));

        // build line 2
        int i = 0;
        output[2].append((i + 1) + SPACER4);
        for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
            output[2].append(String.format(FORMAT_FIRST_ROW, Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j)));
        }

        // build line 3+
        for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            output[i + 2].append((i + 1) + SPACER4);
            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
                output[i + 2].append(String.format(FORMAT_ADDITIONAL_ROWS, Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j)));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

This gives good separation of functionality, keeps strings out of logic code, and minimizes main to only essential calls. Also uses StringBuilder to build the result. This allows you to maintain separation of functionality. Code should do one thing, ie calculate results but not print them. Technically, this should have been separated into it's own class.

On a side note, I would not turn this in as your homework your teacher might just get a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

**Final Result:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter value of N: ");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\t");
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
        }
        System.out.println();

        String barrier = "\t";
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        barrier += "----\t";
        System.out.println(barrier);

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + "");
            for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
                System.out.printf("\t%.2f", Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

First of all, you used `7.2f` in your `printf()`, which was a pain to troubleshoot. The `7` in `7.2f` states that you want the output to always be 7 spaces long, regardless of number length. This is not equal to the amount added by `\t`, so the columns don't line up. To create the `----` barriers under each line, I used a `for` loop to add `N` sections. It should be easy to add the `|`s.

In regards to

> The first actual row of data should not include 1.00, 2.00, 3.00

I don't know what you really want. I'm not sure what you want the first value to be - it seems to follow the `Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j)` calculation that you are using to generate the data for the other rows.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I must have messed up my i & j because 1 should be 1.41

Comment: What I had to do was add 1 to i since it starts at 0. Thanks for the help.